# Google Play Store Cardview

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-cardview

I have been trying for a long time to make Cards similar to appearance that of Google Play Store, ie cards of Different sizes , with images and all inside the card. Any tips on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what kind of tips you're looking for? Are you looking for references to GUI components that will help you build it? are you looking for some specific functionality from the cards? things like that. Good luck! :)

Comment: i want references to GUI components to build them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just create a layout (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc) as a child of your cardview element and make it look however you want.
For example...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        //Your desired layout here    

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can take a look at the [MaterialList](https://github.com/dexafree/MaterialList) implementations for some good examples.